# Input elements change order when typing

Tags: javascript, html, ios, reactjs, mobile

Whenever I begin typing into an input element the inputs change position. This only happens on mobile devices, I've never had this problem on my computer. I've attached a gif showing the issue I encountered. I've been trying to figure out what is causing this issue for a while now but can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated!

[image: Input test gif]

Comment: It's the normal behavior of mobile browsers, which focuses the input field and moves the content offset near the input field.

Comment: Its not just moving the focussed input field.. but email and password are getting swapped

Comment: @mrpineapples, I dont see any issue on my mobile..

Comment: I guess it might be some apple devices. I tried on 2 iphones and my ipad and it kept doing this.

Comment: @Raptor since this is the normal behavior is there anyway to get around this?

Comment: I don't think so. This is good user experience to users. It's better not to change the "normal behavior"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using an array to render this input elements.

I have found the solution of this problem. Basically I found that Safari (only) mess up with array position ordering everytime something is updated in it. What I did was sort the array(which contain your input element configuration) based on some key/id before rendering everytime and it worked.

[source](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2573821)

Comment: Thanks! Since I'm only using two inputs (email and password) I just made sure to sort the array based on the name of each input so it'll always be email before password. Appreciate the help as I'm finally able to fix this annoying bug!